# Tumblr unwanted padding in upload video and audio

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, tumblr

Editing [this tumblr theme](https://clustertheme.tumblr.com/), i tried every kind of post and realize that when I upload an audio track or a video clip, the caption text has a huge padding, and it dosn't happen with embed videos or music.

I tried changing padding and margin in all posible places but doesn't do anything. Don't know where else to look at, so i leave the code with my changes.

This is my tumblr, i've made some changes https://liquidacolectiva.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block that looks like

```css
article img, article iframe, article object {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

You can remove the `height: auto` line. The Tumblr media player was becoming bigger than it should because of that.